# git-tfs clone creates empty folder

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I am trying to clone a project from TFS using git-tfs tool.

```
git tfs clone http://aserver:8080/tfs.... $//ABC/Proj1
```

Result is a folder with empty git repository which contains history of commits but there are no source code files in it and none of the commits contains diff.

Am I wrong expecting to have a directory with source code plus a git repo with commits history with diffs? What can be done to get achieve this result?

Thank you

Comment: The problem should come from the path $//ABC/Proj1 that should not be the good one.

Comment: Thanks, but git-tfs was throwing NullReferenceException when I was trying it with $/ABC/Proj1. Double // solved the problem. :)

Comment: Thanks for all trying to help. I found another tool (git-tf) which worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The part "/Proj1" is redundant.

For example, if you have a project named "Pro1" in TFS default collection, you just need to run the code following:

```
git tfs clone http://aserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/Pro1
```